# Why should I choose ASP.NET Core with .Net core?

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, .net-core, asp.net-core-1.0

Now, I see there are two option when we create ASP.net core web application.

- ASP.Net core Web Application with .Net Core
- ASP.NET Core Web Application with .Net Framework

What I understand is the first one enables us to run it on any environment linux, mac, windows without having .net preinstalled.

For sure, I'm going to run my WebAPI only on Windows environment. In that case, which one I should choose? ASP.Net core Web Application with .Net Core or ASP.Net core Web Application with .Net Framework?

What is the benefit in choosing ASP.Net core Web Application with .Net Core when I'm planning to run only in Windows? I need to create new WebAPI. Dependencies is not an issue, this is going to be very simple basi web api, so i believe i can do in either of them without having any dependencies on some old component which is built on .Framework 4.6.*

Also, what is the difference between ASP.NET Core Web Application with .Net Framework and ASP.NET Web Application with .Net Framework?

Answer (score 8):

There are a few advantages when using .NET Core:

1. Smaller apps because you include only the packages that you need
2. Smaller attack area because of #1: you include only what your app actually uses
3. Easier deployment if you go the self-contained app route
4. (probably) Better support and upgradability long term
5. Possibility of moving to Linux hosting in the future

The biggest disadvantage is that some NuGet packages might not work (yet) on .NET Core. Based on what your app uses, that might be the ultimate decision factor.

Answer (score 0):

Your app can target both until you have a package dependency that runs only on full .net framework. For exemple: NHibernate. Then, you need to target only the full .net framework.

ASP.Net Web Application (.NET Framework) is to create projects in the old format (For exemple: WebForms)

Asp.Net Core Web Applications is to create projects in the new format. Then you can target core or full .net framework

You can find more info [here](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/fundamentals/choosing-the-right-dotnet.html).